# Using Entity Framework migrations, how can I update multiple schemas?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-migrations, database-schema, multi-tenant

I have a database with system-specific tables and another database with user-specific tables which all follow the same structure. We dynamically create a schema for each user to separate their information and toggle which schema we're targetting as needed. That works great for querying as we use 2 different dbcontexts, 1 with our system tables and another which we use for the user tables as we only need to to switch the schema we are pointing to. The issue is with  migrations - we need to be able to tell EF to look through the 50 schemas that exist in the user database and to run the migration for all 50 of them, preferably with their own migration history table.

I understand that this is non-trivial, but I know multi-tenant architecture with separate schemas is not that uncommon. I have seen this working with flyway in Java.

Comment: i am not sure if it is possible for native migration tool (since it already includes schema in migration file), but it is definitely possible through FluentMigrator https://fluentmigrator.github.io/ 

The downside of this approach is that you need to write all migrations with your own hands. But I am not a fan of EF Migrations, so it is rather a plus for me.

Comment: I don't expect to be able to use the cli, so I am OK with migrating in the startup. I just need to be able to change the schema that is being pointed to in a for loop as I will already have the schema names available while everything else is the same.

Comment: Maybe I could create a template schema and use that to build the migrations from when I'm targetting the others.